# Time Series: How to Deal With Differences In Public Holidays?

Tags: time-series, modeling, finance

I am conducting analysis on the relationship between stock markets in regions with differences in the date of public holidays. That is, in some countries, Friday and Saturday are public holidays while in others it is Saturday and Sunday. What could I do to rectify this?

Comment: This could depend on which analysis or models you use, but a possibility could be dummy variables. Then there should be no problem that holidays fall on different dates. Maybe you could add some more information, which models do you intend to use?